# Android Paths for real time charting

Tags: android, charts, android-canvas

I'm trying to create a real-time charting utility in android, and for the most part it works, except that when I get too many data points in one of my Paths it breaks openGL.  I'm using paths because I'm transforming the entire dataset via matrix when a passed in value is outside the current bounds of the graph.  Am I going about this the wrong way? is there a better/more appropriate API for this sort of thing?  I'd be happy to trim the path to the current bounds if that were possible/I knew how to do it.  Thanks!

onDraw:

```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    scaleX = getWidth()  / (maxX - minX);
    scaleY = getHeight() / (maxY - minY);
    // TODO: Use clips to draw x/y axis, allow color to be defined in attributes, etc.
    canvas.drawColor(0xFF000000);
    for (DataLine line : mPathList.values()) {
      canvas.drawPath(line, line.getPaint());
    }
  }
```

(DataLine is a subclass of Path that includes a Paint object)

Error in question is a warning from the OpenGLRenderer: 
"Shape path too large to be rendered into a texture"

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? We cannot help you a lot without knowing the exceptions and your current code.

Comment: I didn't post because there's not a lot to it.... but I'll do so anyway

Comment: I assume that you are developing your app for honeycomb and higher since you mentioned that you use hardwware accelerated canvas. If thats the case you need also to keep in mind that changing a path is very costly. (it will basically result in a new texture upload). If the number of points you are drawing is very low (like some dozen) then you can get away with drawing all points on every frame (even when doing something like cubic approximation etc)

Comment: @Renard, Yes, honeycomb+, but currently the code is probably simple enough that I could skip the acceleration if it proves a problem for pre-3.2

Comment: @Renard As far as number of points go, It will depend on the function being graphed and the domain/range.  Its really dependent upon what the API consumer wants to do

Comment: What i am saying is that the acceleration can be a problem for honeycomb and later if you change your path every frame :-) Also it is not possible to use anti alias for line drawing when hardware acceleration is active. A solution can be to simple keep a list of your points where you remove old points and add new ones. then simple draw the points manually. I also have sample code for that..

Comment: @Renard And by 'draw manually', you mean the 'drawLines' method in Canvas?

Comment: exactly. It basically boils down to this. Do you want "pretty" anti aliased lines? then you must deactivate hardware accelaration. But then you performance will drop when drawing more than a couple of hundred lines. On the plus side: You can use the path object and functions like quadto which will give nice round graphs. When you activate hardware acceleration you can draw several hundred(or thousand) of lines easily. But they will look jagged.

Comment: @Renard I turned off H/W acceleration and it fixed the error, at least.  I'm still a little worried about the size of my path but I think the canvas region is smart enough to do most of that for me.  Anyway write something like all the above as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you looked in your logs you will notice an error like so:

> 04-04 10:39:06.314: W/OpenGLRenderer(6092): Shape path too large to be
>   rendered into a texture

Since turning on hardware acceleration everything gets rendered as a texture and there is a size limit for textures. If you break down the larger shapes into smaller ones, that will solve your problem. Or just turn off hardware acceleration:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: It has solved my problem. But `ScrolleView` has started lagging!

Comment: There are options to set what views you want to be hardware accelerated or not in code. Otherwise do it in another activity without the "android:hardwareAccelerated="false"" flag.